# How to do stripe test payment using its simple checkout

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

all i'm using stripe for the very first time. I've created a account at stripe and i've switched to test mode. I'm using its simple checkout and also using test API key from my account. But when i make the charge using its dummy credit card numbers, it successfully charge but nothing shows up in my account.

```
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

  <button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

  <script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: the_key,
  image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
  // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
  // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
  }
  });

  $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
  name: 'User1',
  description: '2 widgets',
  amount: 2000
  });
  e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation:
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
  });
  </script>
```

I don't know what's wrong with the code why i'm not getting test payments to my account. Help Appreciated.

Comment: See your balance if payment is successful. https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/balance

Comment: I'm in test mode already and there are no changes in balance

Comment: verify your test mode API key and check Stripe response after successful payement

Comment: What do you mean how should i verify ?

Comment: Verify mean check your API key (in code)  which matches with Stripe's key or not.

Comment: @NitinDhomse I've verified it and key is correct

Answer (score -1):

As i have go through your code snippet,you need to hit the server side method for stripe checkout.
I hope this will help you.Let me know if you face with anything.

Comment: I don't much time use API, that's why i'm using simple checkout. So please help me with this simple checkout method

Comment: Checkout securely accepts your customer's payment details and directly passes them to Stripe's servers and then Stripes server return the token which can be submitted to your server. I suggest you to go this link https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple